# How to print multiple datagridview's using printdocument c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform app that will show the user 3 different datagridviews with the relevant data they are enquiring about. I have allowed for the user to select which grids to print out. I can print the first page fine but after that it get an index error. I want it to be setup like any other print out where this one dialog box and they all print out in one document. Example if they select all 3 then 3 pages print. If they select just one then just that one. If they select two then those two print. How beyond the first page can you add the other grids?

Print button click event:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
printDialog.Document = printDocument2;
printDialog.Document = printDocument3;
printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
{
    if (chkBoxByScale.Checked)
    {
         printDocument1.DocumentName = "Project Report";
         printDocument1.Print();
     }
     if (chkBoxByUser.Checked)
     {
         printDocument2.DocumentName = "Project Report 2";
         printDocument2.Print();
     }
     if (chkBoxByLine.Checked)
     {
         printDocument3.DocumentName = "Project Report 3";
         printDocument3.Print();
     }
}
```

If you want me to provide nay of the PrintBegin or PrintPage let me know. Seemed very lengthy for posting all.

Comment: What is the error and at what point in the code is it thrown?

Comment: Not that we need super lengthy code, but the code you posted isn't helpful.  We'll need to see something from your BeginPrint and PrintPage methods.  Chances are, you aren't using the correct scope for your looping variable.